# FactoryGirl has_many association with two-way presence validation creates extra record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, factory-bot

I'm new to FactoryGirl, and I'm having trouble with this specific use case, which doesn't seem to be covered in the documentation.

I have two models, Person and Book. A person has many books, a book belongs to a person, and both have a validation that require each other's presence. (A book must have a person, and a person must have at least one book.)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, inverse_of: :person
  validates :books, presence: true
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  validates :person, presence: true
end
```

I need factories for Person and Book that satisfy the minimum validation requirements of their models. The Person factory should create at least one Book, and the Book factory should create one Person.

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do

    transient do
      books_count 1
    end

    after :build do |person, evaluator|
      person.books << FactoryGirl.build_list(:book, evaluator.books_count, person: person)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :book do
    association :person
  end
end
```

This code works for `FactoryGirl.create(:person)`. However, when I run `FactoryGirl.create(:book)`, the following happens:

1. A book record is created
2. A person record is created
3. A SECOND, unwanted book record is created by the Person factory.

If I change the Book factory's person association to include a books_count of 0, as in `association :person, books_count: 0`, then I get the error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Books can't be blank`, because ActiveRecord thinks that the new Person record has no books.

I want the book factory to create one book and one person, and have each of them satisfy each other's requirements.

How can I change this code so that running `FactoryGirl.create(:book)` will create the required person and then stop there?

Comment: How is this possible to do?  You can't create a Person without first creating a Book and you can't create a Book without first creating a Person.  This is a circular dependency and AR will freak out with a "You cannot call create until a parent is saved".  Even if you got it working FG, I don't get the real life use case

Comment: Ah, okay. So you're saying that the circular dependency is illogical and there's no reason why I would want to do that? That would explain why there's no documentation on this subject.

Comment: To explain myself: The reason I wanted to make both require each other is because it seems like it would be a waste of space to have a Person in the database without a Book, just as it would be a waste of space to have a Book in the database without a Person. Neither are useful without the other, so I figured they should require each other. Is there any validity to that argument, or should I remove the requirement that a Person have at least one Book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize @Anthony's comment on the question:

It is illogical for two objects to require each other, because one must exist before the other exists. So, it is possible for a person to require books:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, inverse_of: :person
  validates :books, presence: true
end
```

Or for a book to require a person:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  validates :person, presence: true
end
```

But both together don't make sense and are thus not supported by Active Record.